# django with nginx + uwsgi does not show templates

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, fapws3

On the Django development server, django app works fine. But once I setup the production test run, I get only the text contents, where template views are not shown as intended. What am I going wrong?

I have 
django 1.5 latest. 
Nginx - 0.8.54
uWSGI - 1.2.5

## cmd for uWSGI:

```
  sudo uwsgi --ini test.ini
```

## test.ini content:

```
[uwsgi]
# set the http port
http = :8080
python_path = /home/test/Desktop/IT_mgmt/IT_mgmt/settings.py/
# change to django project directory
chdir = /home/test/Desktop/IT_mgmt
# load django
module = IT_mgmt.wsgi
```

Answer (score 0):

Nginx should manage your static files, try to access on your CSS or JS ...

nginx.conf for example:

```
location ^~ /static/ {
    }
```